# What 4e character options allow a player to substitute ability scores?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation

There are a number of D&D 4e character creation options that allow players to substitute one ability score in place of another under certain conditions. Here are some examples:

> **Auspicious Birth** or **Born Under A Bad Sign** backgrounds
>
> Benefit: You substitute your highest ability score for Constitution to determine your initial hit points.

**... or ...**

> **Melee Training** feat
>
> Benefit: Choose an ability other than Strength. When you make a melee basic attack using a weapon with which you have proficiency, you can use the chosen ability instead of Strength for the attack roll. In addition, you can use half of that ability’s modifier, instead of your Strength modifier, for the damage roll.

**What options are there for 4e characters to substitute one ability score for another?**

Comment: This question is too broad. Please tell us *which* thing you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Corion are you looking for something like basing your Init. off a stat other than dex or changing how MBAs work?

Comment: Trying to figure out legitimate alternative stat combinations to use with classes (such as what can substitute for AC or whether I could use CHA to make RBA's). These questions come up so many times when building characters, and I could not find a comprehensive list anywhere online. I didn't realize it wasn't a good fit for SE when I posted it. I'm compiling a list on the Giant In The Playground forums if anyone wants to know or help out.

Comment: Here is the thread where the list is being compiled, for those interested: [Ability Score Substitution](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?p=15212319)